# mystery checkbox in comments area

Tags: updates

Since I updated Wordpress, a checkbox appears in the comments area of my pages (see first screen capture). I did an "inspect element" and the checkbox seems to have to do with cookies consent (see second screen capture), but there's nothing written next to it, and I don't know if I can remove it.

Does anyone know anything about this?

[image: mystery checkbox]
[image]

My site is http://twinpeaksreviews.com. Checkbox doesn't appear on the front page, which doesn't have a comments area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to respect the new (May 25 2018) European Union law "The General Data Protection Regulation" (GDPR).

When checkbox is checked, it says the browser to save the name, email and website in the cookie to reuse them later.

When comment form `<label>` is CSS-styled the right way, the label text "*Save my name, email, and website in this browser for the next time I comment.*" it visible. Also you can inspect it in Developer Tools like you've done with `<input>`.

If you are not affected by GDPR, simply remove the checkbox putting the following code in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'comment_form_hide_cookies_consent' );

function comment_form_hide_cookies_consent( $fields )
{
    unset( $fields['cookies'] );
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark it as "Answered". To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Thanks - I was actually looking fora button to indicate that my question was answered. I wouldn't have known to click on the checkmark!